# PreparedStatement in ItemPreparedStatementSetter which lets db-engine to auto-generate IDs

Tags: spring-batch

Is there a way to have `PreparedStatement` in `ItemPreparedStatementSetter` from Spring Batch configured in a way it will let db engine generate IDs on the fly?

Typically, you would set it up while creating statement from `java.sql.Connection`:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"ID"})
```

I'd like to avoid exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
ORA-01400: 
cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."TABLE"."ID")
```

Comment: what DB you are using? Normally, almost DB has getNextVal() method to get next id.

Comment: I'm using Oracle. To what getNextVal() method are you referring? I have sequences defined, but these are used when using JPA, but not in ItemPreparedStatementSetter context. I also know I could use JPA Item writer, but I need JDBC one, because of performance

Comment: Please so me the 'sql' value.

Comment: Your comments don't seem to be relevant for my question

Comment: I'd like to see the 'sql' variable which you are using in prepareStatement to see how you generate ID. For Oracle we normally use 'sequenceName'.nextval. For example, your 'sql' should be 'insert into TABLE (id, name) values (idseq.nextval,'Patrik')

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use Oracle sequence in sql:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (ID) VALUES (SEQ_NAME.nextval)";
```